# Import .net or .bz2 file to Python as network using NetworkX

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I've downloaded a data set with filename .net (or .bz2) and I want to import it to iPython Notebook to create a network with the data set with the use of NetworkX, however I haven't been able to find how to import the file.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Could you tell us more about the format of the file? See http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/readwrite.html for info about file  formats you can read into networkx.

Comment: [link](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/dic/eat/Eat.htm) Pajek, we got the network from this link

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have downloaded and decompressed the ZIP file:

```
import networkx as nx

fyle = 'eatRS.net'
G = nx.read_pajek(fyle)
# G now contains the network
print(len((G.nodes())))
```